# Handling window.postMessage() Events Not Triggering in a React iframe

Tags: reactjs, postmessage

I'm building a React iframe that is hosted on client websites. The client website passes information to the iframe using `window.postMessage()`.

The client attempts to pass previous conversation history by making an internal call and then passing that information through the following code:

```js
window.postMessage({
  action: "updateConversations",
  conversations: // conversation data here
}, targetOrigin);
```

However, no matter what I do, `handleMessage` is not getting triggered. The `console.log` inside `handleMessage` is not getting printed at all. I'm wondering if the delay in response from the client server is causing this issue or if it's something else.

Here is my code snippet:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  if (urlParams.has("projectID")) {
    setProjectID(urlParams.get("projectID"));
  }

  const widgetURL = `${apiURL}/widget/${urlParams.get("projectID")}`;

  async function fetchData() {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(widgetURL);
      const data = await response.json();
      setWidgetData(data.widget);
      window.parent.postMessage({ action: "getConversationData" }, data.widget.eventOriginEmbed);

      const handleMessage = (event) => {
        console.log("event.origin", event.origin);
        console.log("event.data.action", event.data.action);

        if (event.origin !== data.widget.eventOriginEmbed) 
          return;

        if (event.data.action === "updateConversations" && event.data.conversations) {
          console.log("Received by frontend", event.data.conversations);
          setConversation(event.data.conversations);
        }
      };

      window.addEventListener("message", handleMessage);
      return () => window.removeEventListener("message", handleMessage);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  const cleanup = fetchData();

  return () => {
    if (typeof cleanup === 'function') {
      cleanup();
    }
  };
}, []);
```

I've included the necessary parts of my code. Any insights or suggestions on what might be causing `handleMessage` to not be triggered would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it would be a solution for you,
but it looks not safe to call `postMessage` before calling `addEventListener`.
How about calling `addEventListener` first before calling `postMessage`?

On the other hand, it looks like you are assigning a promise for `cleanup`, not a function. `typeof cleanup === 'function'` will always be false, and the `cleanup` call will never be executed. I think you should fix it using `await`.